# how to convert image file into image bytes

Tags: c#

can you guys help to convert a JPG File into an 2-dimensional int [] [] array?! There´s a solution to convert it to a bytearray, but i need it in an int array....

```
byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("example.jpg");
```

Comment: Do you need the image's pixels as int values or just the raw bytes of the file?

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need this to be working in WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReadAllBytes will not get you the pixels of the JPEG. JPEG is a compressed image type. You need to load it into an Image class first to uncompress it. Then you can access the pixels of the image plus determine the width and height of it.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap("example.jpg"); 

// Loop through the image
for(x=0; x<image.Width; x++)
{
    for(y=0; y<image.Height; y++)
    {
        Color pixelColor = image1.GetPixel(x, y);
        my_int_array[x][y] = pixelColor.ToArgb();
    }
}
```

Comment: i know that the mentioned function not get the pixels...The Question is how to get the pixels in my int array...

Answer (score 2):

If you need to provide raw access to the underlying image for some image processing API (which is most likely what you actually need) and not access to the *file* then see [How to: Use LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229672%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

this article also covers some basics like scans and stride: [Using the LockBits method to access image data](https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx).